# Row inside OutlinedButton

Tags: flutter

How to get the OutlinedButton as long as the Row's content ? I have this button inside Column <- SizedBox(width:300) <- Card

```
OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: null,
        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
          fixedSize: const Size.fromHeight(40),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(widget.leading,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'JT', fontSize: 18, color: widget.color)),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text(widget.txt,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'NunitoEB', fontSize: 16, color: widget.color)),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text(widget.suffix,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'JT', fontSize: 18, color: widget.color)),
          ],
        ));
```

Comment: Sorry to say but your Question is not clear yet

Comment: The button has an infinite width

Comment: Add the full class code? Make sure your question is clear before posting it.

Comment: You initially informed me of the width of your button before mentioning a container issue.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm Try To Solve Your Problem :**

Use **`SizedBox`** to Set Width of `OutlinedButton`

**Here is Code:**

```
SizedBox(
        width: 250,
        height: 50,
        child: OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: null,
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              fixedSize: const Size.fromHeight(40),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(widget.leading,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'JT', fontSize: 18, color: widget.color)),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text(widget.txt,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'NunitoEB', fontSize: 16, color: widget.color)),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text(widget.suffix,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'JT', fontSize: 18, color: widget.color)),
              ],
            )),
      );
```

[image]

Comment: Tested and doesn't work. My OutlinedButton is inside ```Column``` <-```SizedBox(width:300)```<-```Card```

Comment: lol! So why do you treat us like fools? Clearly state your question before posting it.

Comment: Like fools ?! Please quote. "Check my Answer i will Solved your problem why you did not Reply me ?" - "Clearly state your question before posting it". You, you're clearly speaking aggresively lmao.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code. what did you do so far? please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information. Good luck

Comment: I tried many solutions, like using Flexible. What can you know about what i tried or not. I can't share more code, I don't have error logs, I tried to make it the easiest to understand (by telling the widget's parents). Thank you for your time. You attack me after 2 messages...Looks like you're having a bad day. May peace be with you

Answer (score -1):

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

use this property in your row

Edit:
[image]

Edit 2:

```
               SizedBox(
                        width: 300,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Spacer(),
                            OutlinedButton(
                                onPressed: null,
                                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                  fixedSize: const Size.fromHeight(40),
                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Text('leading',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'JT',
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                        )),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Text('txt',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'NunitoEB',
                                            fontSize: 16)),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Text('suffix',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'JT',
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                        )),
                                  ],
                                )),
                            Spacer(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
```

try this out and see if it works even with your container as parent

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't work

Comment: @Jordaninho I have added a picture of how it appears for me, if this is not what you are looking for then can you elaborate?

Comment: @Jordaninho Check my Answer i will Solved your problem why you did not Reply me ?

Comment: @Jordaninho have updated my answer, I wrapped the button in a Row and added a Spacer each on both the sides so button takes the min space. Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry still not ok. My button is inside Column <- SizedBox <- Card. Maybe it helps you

Comment: @Jordaninho This code works for me in the scenarios you had said, can you share your code via dartpad so we can see where it goes wrong.